# Can't make a request to local server

Tags: java, android-studio, android-volley

So I'm starting with android studio, following tutorials and all.

I'm interested in making a request to a local server, so I google up and see this.

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple

I follow the instructions, get stuck in a couple of places being a very new user to java and android studio, but everything works in the end.

Then, knowing the app will work, just change the "http://www.google.com" string in the example with the ip of the server. And nothing happens.

It doesn't retrieve the index page.
I try with a php script. Nothing.
Phone and server are in the same LAN.
I have tried adding "http://" to the ip, nothing.
Server just work fine in any browser, pc and phone.

I am missing something?

If the code is needed I upload it, but it's exactly the same in the example.

```
public class MainActivity extends     AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void sendRequest(){
        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stringRequest);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="http://192.168.1.36";
        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                textView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                textView.setText("That didn't work!");
            }
        });

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    public void onClick(View view){
        sendRequest();
    }
}
```

Logcat throws this error:

```
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

Also, I tried to run it on a emulator and the result is the same.

I added every network related permission, too.

Comment: Yes, you should always share your code to show what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you changed is `https://www.google.com` to `http://1.2.3.4` (note switching https to http, and leaving the protocol in the string URL), and it works fine with google there but not with your IP, then it means where-ever you're running this code (on your phone directly, or on the emulator in your dev environment) cannot reach that IP. Note that if you wait a while, the code will error out with for example a Destination Unreachable error or something else enlightening.

Comment: I think the way the program is written it will not throw any error. How could can i modify to get a more clear error message?